# How to compute sensitivity, specificity from a fitted logistic glm?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, roc, threshold

I have fitted a **logistic glm**. Now I want to calculate **sensitivity, specificity** i.e., **true positive rate, false positive rate**.

I can easily calculate **AUC** using the `R` package `pROC`. Since, logistic model returns probabilities as fitted value, to calculate AUC, a bunch of **thresholds (cut off values)** are used (I don't know how many).

But, for sensitivity specificity I think only **one threshold** is needed.
So should I randomly select a threshold and calculate sensitivity, specificity???

Or is there any package that can return their values?

This is a sample code, any help is extremely appreciated.

```
library(pROC)
set.seed(1)
x1=rnorm(50)
x2=rnorm(50)
y=rbinom(50,1, 0.5)
dat=data.frame(y,x1,x2)
Model1=glm(y~.,family=binomial,data=dat)
Pred1=predict(Model1, newdata=dat, type="response")
Roc1=roc(dat$y, Pred1) #this gives roc
AUC1=auc(Roc1) #this returns auc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Youden's J statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youden%27s_J_statistic) to identify the optimal threshold using the `pROC::coords()` and `epi.tests` from the `epiR` package for the accuracy metrics:

```
# Using Youden's j index, as an option for optimal cut point
youdbest <- pROC::coords(Roc1, "b", ret = "threshold", best.method = "youden")

# confusion matrix
cM <- table(ifelse(Pred1 > youdbest[[1]], 1, 0), dat$y)

# Accuracy metrics
epiR::epi.tests(cM)

#> epiR::epi.tests(cM)
#          Outcome +    Outcome -      Total
#Test +           22           13         35
#Test -            6            9         15
#Total            28           22         50
#
#Point estimates and 95% CIs:
#--------------------------------------------------------------
#Apparent prevalence *                  0.70 (0.55, 0.82)
#True prevalence *                      0.56 (0.41, 0.70)
#Sensitivity *                          0.79 (0.59, 0.92)
#Specificity *                          0.41 (0.21, 0.64)
#Positive predictive value *            0.63 (0.45, 0.79)
#Negative predictive value *            0.60 (0.32, 0.84)
#Positive likelihood ratio              1.33 (0.89, 1.98)
#Negative likelihood ratio              0.52 (0.22, 1.25)
#False T+ proportion for true D- *      0.59 (0.36, 0.79)
#False T- proportion for true D+ *      0.21 (0.08, 0.41)
#False T+ proportion for T+ *           0.37 (0.21, 0.55)
#False T- proportion for T- *           0.40 (0.16, 0.68)
#Correctly classified proportion *      0.62 (0.47, 0.75)
#--------------------------------------------------------------
#* Exact CIs
```

Answer (score 1):

One potential options is the `confusionMatrix()` function from the [caret package](https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/man/confusionMatrix.html), e.g.

```r
library(pROC)

set.seed(1)
x1=rnorm(50)
x2=rnorm(50)
y=rbinom(50,1, 0.2)
dat=data.frame(y,x1,x2)
Model1=glm(y~.,family=binomial,data=dat)
Pred1=predict(Model1, newdata=dat, type="response")
Roc1=roc(dat$y, Pred1) #this gives roc
#> Setting levels: control = 0, case = 1
#> Setting direction: controls < cases
AUC1=auc(Roc1) #this returns auc
AUC1
#> Area under the curve: 0.748

library(caret)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: lattice
binary_outcome <- ifelse(Pred1 > 0.1, 1, 0)
confusionMatrix(as.factor(binary_outcome), as.factor(dat$y))
#> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#> 
#>           Reference
#> Prediction  0  1
#>          0 10  1
#>          1 31  8
#>                                           
#>                Accuracy : 0.36            
#>                  95% CI : (0.2292, 0.5081)
#>     No Information Rate : 0.82            
#>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               
#>                                           
#>                   Kappa : 0.0577          
#>                                           
#>  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 2.951e-07       
#>                                           
#>             Sensitivity : 0.2439          
#>             Specificity : 0.8889          
#>          Pos Pred Value : 0.9091          
#>          Neg Pred Value : 0.2051          
#>              Prevalence : 0.8200          
#>          Detection Rate : 0.2000          
#>    Detection Prevalence : 0.2200          
#>       Balanced Accuracy : 0.5664          
#>                                           
#>        'Positive' Class : 0               
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You need to set a 'threshold' for evaluating the outcomes (e.g. in this case I used <0.1 or >0.1) and if you change the threshold you will change the Sensitivity and Specificity (this is one of the reasons why AUC is used).

---

### Edit 1

If you are unable to install caret for some reason, a potential workaround is to copy the source code for the `confusionMatrix()` function from the link I posted ([confusion_matrix](https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/src/R/confusionMatrix.R)) into a file on your system, then `source()` the file to use that specific function. E.g. I downloaded the source code into a file on my desktop called "conf_matrix.R", then ran the command as described:

```r
library(pROC)

set.seed(1)
x1=rnorm(50)
x2=rnorm(50)
y=rbinom(50,1, 0.2)
dat=data.frame(y,x1,x2)
Model1=glm(y~.,family=binomial,data=dat)
Pred1=predict(Model1, newdata=dat, type="response")
Roc1=roc(dat$y, Pred1) #this gives roc
#> Setting levels: control = 0, case = 1
#> Setting direction: controls < cases
AUC1=auc(Roc1) #this returns auc
AUC1
#> Area under the curve: 0.748

source("~/Desktop/conf_matrix.R")
binary_outcome <- ifelse(Pred1 > 0.1, 1, 0)
confusionMatrix(as.factor(binary_outcome), as.factor(dat$y))
#> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#> 
#>           Reference
#> Prediction  0  1
#>          0 10  1
#>          1 31  8
#>                                           
#>                Accuracy : 0.36            
#>                  95% CI : (0.2292, 0.5081)
#>     No Information Rate : 0.82            
#>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               
#>                                           
#>                   Kappa : 0.0577          
#>                                           
#>  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 2.951e-07       
#>                                           
#>             Sensitivity : 0.2439          
#>             Specificity : 0.8889          
#>          Pos Pred Value : 0.9091          
#>          Neg Pred Value : 0.2051          
#>              Prevalence : 0.8200          
#>          Detection Rate : 0.2000          
#>    Detection Prevalence : 0.2200          
#>       Balanced Accuracy : 0.5664          
#>                                           
#>        'Positive' Class : 0               
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: yes. Thanks. But, I know about caret package. However, I have several failed attempt installing it in my computer. (I tried different version of R too). Do you know about any other package?

Comment: This is the function/package that I use in my own work; I don't know of an alternative. A potential workaround is to download the source code then `source()` the file; I'll edit my answer to explain how to do it

Comment: Hello Dr @jared_mamrot I have a request please have a look at this question its kind of similar https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/613879/how-to-compare-two-signature-for-prediction-models

Comment: Sorry @PesKchan, your stats question completely slipped my mind! I completely agree with everything in EdM's answer, and I can't think of anything else to add - does their answer make sense to you? Were you able to implement it with your actual data?

Comment: yes after 5-6 try and gathering codes from here and there finally I understood EdM's suggestion which i was able to implement

Comment: I would like to use your above solution for ROC curve, my stat question was whether my two models have the same or they are different in terms of survival prediction

Answer (score 1):

With pROC you can easily obtain a "best" threshold (warning, there may be more than one) with the [`coords` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/topics/coords):

```
coords(Roc1, x="best")
```

This assumes your cost function is equal for false negative and false positives. This is rarely the case, but you can set optional weights to change that:

```
coords(Roc1, x="best", best.weights=c(5, 0.2))
```

See [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/topics/coords) ("Best thresholds" section) on how to properly set these weights for your use case.